# Is there a way to fully load a turret in Factorio?

Tags: factorio

For the defense of my factory I use Gun Turrets. I've got a belt with magazines running past them. However when there are a lot of biters/spitters coming the belt can't provide fast enough so some turrets run out of ammo. Now I know that ammo magazines stacks up to 200, but the inserters only put 10 magazines in the turret. Is there a way (I'm playing without mods) to get the inserters to fully load the turret, or put a specific number in the turret? I've been trying with circuits a bit, but I'm not a specialist in that and I haven't succeeded. So if anyone knows how to do this, thanks a lot in advance!

PS: I know the system with requester chests and stack inserters, but my factory is quite big and I don't want that many bots flying to very distant places.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, but what you can do is give each turret its own chest, then supply that chest from the belt.  You can limit the chest to only one slot using the red icon in the chest-UI.

Answer (score 2):

I use a mod for this, by putting this into `data-final-fixes.lua`

```
for _, turret in pairs (data.raw["ammo-turret"]) do
   if turret.automated_ammo_count > 2 then
      turret.automated_ammo_count = 2
   end
end
```

This limits the inserted ammo to 2. Results are mixed - at high levels, this can quickly lead to shortages as the inserters are not fast enough to load more form a belt.